# Objects with different Constructors

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am working on a button program thing. I have a `Button` object that is assigned to each button that is found in the HTML. Since there are different types of buttons, I want there to be a different constructor to make the object suited for each type.

I understand how I would go about calling these separate constructors, but I do not know what to put in the constructors to make it apply certain variables to the `Button` Object.

**Example Button Object:**

```
var Button = function(){
    if (buttonType == 'type1'){
        buttonType1(); //set onclick, onmouseover/mouseout, onmousedown/mouseup
    }
    else{
        buttonType2(); //set different ways to handle events
    }
}
```

**How a `Button` Object is created:**

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

Buttons = new Buttons_Objs(); //An object to store references to all Button Objs.

for (i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++){
    button = buttons[i];
    buttonType = button.getAttribute('type');
    Buttons['button' + i] = new Button(button, buttonType);
}
```

How would I structure those functions to set the onclick and stuff, and where would be a good place to store them if I do not want them crowding up my `Button` Object.

Comment: this smells like a school assignment. anyway, the terms you are using do not reflect what little code you have presented above. can you provide all the code you are dealing with so your question can answered more precisely?

Comment: @zero It is not a school assignment, I start Computer Science next semester, this is just a personal project for learning.
Is it appropriate to send you my test page that I work on?

Comment: @zero I added some code showing how each `Button` Object is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have presented is a normal javascript function (not a constructor function) which you can add an argument to like this:

```
var Button = function(buttonType){
    if (buttonType == 'type1'){
        buttonType1(); //set onclick, onmouseover/mouseout, onmousedown/mouseup
    }
    else{
        buttonType2(); //set different ways to handle events
    }
}
```

And, you would then call like this:

```
Button("type1");
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a proper constructor function, as I am confused.

Comment: Wow, I am so derp, I missed what you put completely, Thanks!